# Formula entry to cell via App Script in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up this formula in a cell and it wont let me save.  I can't figure out how to get this into a cell

```
quotelist.getRange("R" + rowNumberForQuote).setFormula("=if(R"&rowNumberForQuote&"="New Quote","New Quote",if(isna(VLOOKUP(B"&rowNumberForQuote&",'Form responses 4'!B:C,2,false))=True,"Sent To Customer",(VLOOKUP(B"&rowNumberForQuote&",'Form responses 4'!B:C,2,false))))");
```

If Cell R Row Number = New Quote then Write "New Quote"
If Not then Vlookup for in B Row Number of Form Reponses 4
If Vlookup is #N/A then Write "Sent to Customer"
if Vlookup finds then display answer

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and be more descriptive about what you mean by "it wont let me save" (is the Google Apps Script IDE the one that wont let you save? Include the textual error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix: Replace the formula (the parameter of `setFormula`):

```
"=if(R"&rowNumberForQuote&"="New Quote","New Quote",if(isna(VLOOKUP(B"&rowNumberForQuote&",'Form responses 4'!B:C,2,false))=True,"Sent To Customer",(VLOOKUP(B"&rowNumberForQuote&",'Form responses 4'!B:C,2,false))))"
```

by

```
`=if(R${rowNumberForQuote}="New Quote","New Quote",if(isna(VLOOKUP(B${rowNumberForQuote},'Form responses 4'!B:C,2,false))=True,"Sent To Customer",(VLOOKUP(B${rowNumberForQuote},'Form responses 4'!B:C,2,false))))`
```

The original formula has syntax errors as it's using `&` instead of `+` and didn't scaped the `"`. The proposed formula use strings template. IHMO this is better because it's easier easier to read and makes unnecessary to escape simple/double quote characters (`'`, `"`).

Another option is to replace the `&` and escape the `"` that should be escaped, like `\"New Quote\"` instead of `"New Quote"` and `\"Sent To Customer\"` instead of `"Sent To Customer"`.